# Remove calendra icon from posts in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

For the couple of hours i have stacked and i cant find a way to remove the calendar icon that is located to the left side of each post. I am curently using the Constructo theme. I already tried

```
.entry-meta .fa-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

and `.fa-calendar { display: none; }` in my custom css but nothing seems to happen can anyone please help me?

Thanks in Regards

Comment: provide HTML or website URL

Comment: Here you go man http://www.psilosgenerators.com/

Comment: the provided url is under maintenance, I am not a logged in user ^_^

Comment: did you try `display:none!important` ?